# How to set state and immediately use that state in a function, for this specific code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a Submit button to update this.state.FormStatus. I will use this state to save to an SP list. But I'm a rookie and getting the well-known stale state issue. I understand that I need to pass a callback to setState. But I don't know how with my code.

I've tried this:

But the syntax is wrong.

```
private _onSubmit() {
    this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
      return {
      FormStatus: prevState.FormStatus: 'Submitted',
      SubmittedLblVis: !prevState.SubmittedLblVistrue,
      };
  });
```

Here is the rest of the Submit and I've corrected the code above, which may help clear things up:

```
 private _onSubmit() {
    this.setState(prevState =>({
      FormStatus: 'Submitted',
      SubmittedLblVis: true,
  }));
      pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("JobEvaluationItems").items.add({

        JobTitle: this.state.JobTitle,
        Faculty: this.state.Faculty,
        Department: this.state.SelectedDept,
        SubDepartment: this.state.SubDepartment,
        DeptContactId: this.state.DeptContact,
        FormStatus: this.state.FormStatus
```

As you can see on the last line of code above, I'm trying to update an SP list with the latest this.state.FormStatus.
I expect the Submit button to add 'Submitted' to this.state.FormStatus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Why not (1) set the "submitted" state value you want, and (2) independently submit the "add" data you want? The only connection between the two is the `state.ForStatus` value, so why wait for react to flush state changes? The other option is to use the `setState` callback method as @Dupocas has pointed out, it runs after the state update has been flushed.

Comment: Do you mean have two separate functions, 1 which sets the state and the other (which is called from within the 1st function maybe?) adds to the list?

Comment: @Tom there already are two functions. I meant to decouple the setting a status in state from form data submission, or in other words, get a new status value, and send it to both state and the list add at the same time, independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the `state` in the wrong way. To read the new state you can use the second parameter from `setState` which provides you a `callback` to be execute only when all state's updated are done

```
private _onSubmit() {
    this.setState( prevState =>({
         FormStatus: 'Submitted',
         SubmittedLblVis: !prevState.SubmittedLblVistrue,
      })
    }, () => console.log('Accessing the current state: ' + this.state.FormStatus));
}
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. Please ignore SubmittedLblVis state by the way.
Should prevState be used on FormStatus somehow? I've updated the code to show how I'm using this.state.FormStatus

Comment: @Tom does the previous state value of `FormStatus` matter? I suspect not since you set it to a string constant that isn't based on the previous value at all.

Comment: @Drew - Hi Drew, no it doesn't matter. It's null on initialisation.

Comment: @Tom you probably just want something simpler like `this.setState({ FormStatus: 'Submitted' }, () => { <all your item add code with new state values > });`. Just remember you also probably want to set that form status back to some default, non-submitted value when the add item code is complete.

Comment: Yes that's it Drew. Thank you.